# Concurrent queue with barrier task only

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, kingfisher

Recently I'm reading the codes of the popular image caching library [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher).

I'm confusing about the GCD usages on the `ImageDownloader`. In that downloader, all the `ImageFetchLoad` (task to fetch image) related operations are dispatched to a concurrent queue called `barrierQueue`:

```
barrierQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.onevcat.Kingfisher.ImageDownloader.Barrier.\(name)", attributes: .concurrent)
```

The confusing part is ALL the operations are dispatched using barrier sync:

```
barrierQueue.sync(flags: .barrier) {
    if let URL = task.internalTask.originalRequest?.url, let imageFetchLoad = self.fetchLoads[URL] {
        imageFetchLoad.downloadTaskCount -= 1
        if imageFetchLoad.downloadTaskCount == 0 {
            task.internalTask.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Every barrier operation will block each other which make the queue actually a serial one. Thus, why the Kingfisher use the `concurrent` queue instead of a `serial` one?

Comment: Don't assume there's a deep reason when it may just be history. Have you reached out to the developer who added the flag? (onevcat: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/commit/c676d71f6f1b780ba51c6f7ee0e9d7b17d61cf5d) Particularly note that before that commit, some used `.barrier` and some didn't: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/blob/76edadd0231e25459ee19d0f63d3ffbe543c4e2c/Sources/ImageDownloader.swift

Comment: Based on my understanding barrier would make sense in concurrent queue, not sure if it would make sense in serial queue because the tasks would be anyway be executed one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some cases where it may make sense to use a `concurrent` queue over a `serial` queue for GCD thread safety. Serial execution may not be desirable or necessary for all operations in a class. For example for "read" operations that do not modify state, it makes sense for them to  perform *concurrently* and synchronously. i.e., if the "read" operation returns information that is not dependent on state that might be modified by other operations you're waiting on, there's no reason to wait for serial execution.

So in these cases you might use a `concurrent` queue as Kingfisher does, and set a `.barrier` flag for any operations that mutate data state to tell the block to wait until all other operations in the queue are complete before executing.

I can't speak to the specific rationale behind Kingfisher's use of a `concurrent` queue, but just wanted to note an example use case of when you might prefer `concurrent` over `serial` for GCD queue safety. Using `concurrent` can provide additional flexibility since you can decide if operations should be executed concurrently or "serially" with a .barrier flag, depending on behavior.

For a description of this pattern, take a look at the `.barrier` description in here: http://khanlou.com/2016/04/the-GCD-handbook/